# json with java i have problew with adding json object to json array

Tags: java, json

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONArray jsar = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsob = new JSONObject();
    jsob.put("Name", "john");
    jsob.put("Age", "21");
    System.out.println(jsob);
    jsar.add(0,jsob);
    jsob.put("Name", "nimal");
    jsob.put("Age", "25");
    System.out.println(jsob);
    jsar.add(1,jsob);
    System.out.println(jsar);
}
```

```
{"Age":"21","Name":"john"}
{"Age":"25","Name":"nimal"}
[{"Age":"25","Name":"nimal"},{"Age":"25","Name":"nimal"}]
```

any help me please why the object with name john is not added to the json array

Comment: You need to create a new JSONObject for each item added.

Comment: In the duplicate, look at the "Adding the Same Object" section, since your problem (and solution) are the same

Comment: Specifically, just before `jsob.put("Name", "nimal");`, call `jsob = new JSONObject();` *again*

Comment: You're welcome, but more important, hopefully you understand *why* it works. Your code is changing the state of a single object, and adding that single object multiple times. The solution creates a new object when needed.